# Not use for loop to read the file

Tags: python

A file, grades.dat, that includes the names and grades of 10
students as shown below are given as an example.The first item is the student's name and the second item is the grade of that student. The code will read the information in the file in a dictionary where student names are keys and their grades are values. The second item in each line that represents a grade will be converted to float
when it is read as a value in the dictionary. The code is expected to print the names
and grades of the students after reading them. A grade is considered success if it
is 70 or above, and failure if it is below 70.

```
Grades.dat
Barbara 62.5
John 85.
Marvin 72.5
Lewis 95.
William 65.
Mary 87.5
Sandra 92.5
Jacob 60.
Leigh 75.
Pamela 67.5
```

```py
file = input("Enter the file name: ") 
try: 
    f=open(file,"r") #c=f.read() 
     #print(c) 
except IOError: 
    print("file does not exist") 
    #print(c)
```

Comment: file = input("Enter the file name: ")
try:
    f=open(file,"r")
    #c=f.read()
    #print(c)
except IOError:
    print("file does not exist")
    #print(c)                                                                                                                                                what me do next?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I read the file .what will be the next step what logic use in this question

Comment: What do you mean `"Not use for loop"`? Is that a constraint of the assignment? A `for` loop is a very standard way to do this. Where you supposed to use some other specific method?

Comment: Split each line, then convert the second value to float using `float()`, then use `if else` to check if score is greater than or less 70. Check this for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510474/read-each-line-of-a-text-file-and-then-split-each-line-by-spaces-in-python

Comment: Cant use for loop is there any other way to read a file and put its contents in a dictionary?

Comment: You can use a `while` loop, but that would be dumb.  A `for` loop is the right way to solve this problem.  The problem itself is poorly stated.  It tells you just to print the names and grades.  It tells you the threshold for success and failure, but it doesn't ask you to do anything with that information.

Comment: @TimRoberts Can you tell me how to do?

Comment: without loop not possible, you can try many fancy way which will use loop under the hood anyway and not much redeable like `dict(map(lambda x: x.split(), open(file,"r").read().split('\n')))`

Comment: yeah @TimRoberts is right...assuming you split the contents of file and obtain everything as separate elements in a list...a for loop is still fundamental to assigning those elements to a dictionary.


Even if u don't use a dictionary...u have to use a loop to traverse the elements of the list

Comment: @ErrorEliminator Maybe "without for loop" here is the instructures way of pushing the students to use a dict comprehension, which admittedly is still a loop.

Comment: Do you have strict instructions not to use a loop? Or are you choosing not to use one because you think it will be easier to understand? Wasn't there a Regex solution posted a few hours ago? Not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Although not a typical way of doing things... This doesn't use a For Loop:

```
f=open(file,"r")

while(True):
    line = f.readline()

    if line == '':
        break

    # Do stuff to make each line fit the requirements
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you cannot use any type of loops. Just for fun, here is another solution to iterate over a list and convert it to dictionary using a list iterator and zip function:

```
file = input("Enter the file name: ") try:
    f=open(file,"r")
    # iterator to a list of lines
    c=iter(f.read().split())
    # zip to create name/grade pairs, then convert to dict
    grades_dict = dict(zip(c,c))
    print(grades_dict)

except IOError:
    print("file does not exist")
```

I'm not sure about the remaining problem definition. Are you allowed to use a loop for printing the output? This is using list comprehension, which is technically a for loop:

```
print ('\n'.join(k + ": Success"
    if float(v) >= 70.0 else k + ": Failure"
        for k,v in grades_dict.items()))
```

*Edit: It is a "Generator Expression," similar to List Comprehension
https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/